# How can I simulate spatial locality?

Tags: testing, simulation, p2p, bittorrent

I want to modify the BitTorrent tracker to select peer sets based on spatial locality. How could I possibly simulate this?

I've thought of using latency but it's not really useful in this scenario since the measured latencies would be between the tracker and individual peers - not between peers.

Comment: Why do you want to select peers based on  spatial locality?

Comment: I am investigating methods to improve BT for streaming purposes. Both in the client and in the tracker. Cherrypicking peer sets based on spatial locality seems interesting in that regard.

Comment: streaming mostly requires some minimum guaranteed throughput for the sequentially fetched parts, not necessarily *lowest* latency. due to asymmetric connections locality does not optimize for througput.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a geoip database to match ip -> city/country , and only select the peers that are close to each other.

Comment: I'm looking for options that allow me to simulate this (or similar) operation(s) since I will be developing and testing on a single machine.